# SSIS Custom Logging Best Practice

Tags: ssis

I was wondering what would be the best way to implement the logging of Execute SQL Task.  For example, for each of my Execute SQL Task component, I would like to log the following :

1)  The description of the SQL Task.
2)  The SQL statement that is used in the SQL Task.
3)  The result of the SQL statement.  The SQL statement is returning a scalar value.
4)  The job run id that SSIS that is creating which is the Operation_Id that SSIS creates.

Currently, this is how I am implementing it which is quite repetitive.

1)  For each Execute SQL Task (lets call it mySQLTask), I create a another Execute SQL Task called "Log Result" in the Post-Execute Event of mySQLTask.
2)  I create a stored procedure called Log_Result which is executed from the "Log Result" Execute SQL Task.
3)  I then copy the SQL statement from mySQLTask and paste it as a hard-coded parameter to the stored procedure parameters. for example, in the "Log Result" SQL task of the SQL Statement properties... "EXEC Log_Result ?,?,'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE',?

Is there a way where I can retrieve the SQL Statement from mySQLTask dynamically? ANd is there a better way to do this?

I have also explored the SSIS in built logging of ExecuteSQLExecutingQuery option in the Logging functionality.  It gives me the SQL statement that was executed but I also want to keep track of the result too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recomend this book and the loging framework contained therein:

**Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Integration Services: Problem, Design, Solution**

[ISBN: 978-0-470-52576-0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470525762)

If I have understood your question correctly I would say it does exactly what you are looking for. [Code download link here.](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Integration-Services-Problem-Design-Solution.productCd-0470525762,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html)

If I have understood your question correctly I would say it can be used to do what you describe if you configure your Execute SQL Task SQLStatement property from a Package Configuration with a SQL Server Configuration type.

This will allow you to keep your SQL statements inside a table in SQL server that you can query and join to other tables that contain logs for each Package Task.

It is very straight forward to set up and quite robust. The authors do an excellent job of walking you through this step by step. Should take you about a day to get it up and running.

Recording the scalar result of the Execute SQL Task would be an enhancement to the SSIS PDS Framework. But I would not worry too much about that: should fit nicely onto the out of the box PackageTaskLog table. I provide the PackageTaskLog script below for your reference.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [adm].[PackageTaskLog](
    [PackageTaskLogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PackageLogID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SourceName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [SourceID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StartDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageTaskLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageTaskLogID] ASC
)
```